# How to convert AutoCAD layers to .shp

Tags: convert, layers, autocad

I have 0 experience in AutoCAD and need to convert some layers to .shp I can use and store in ArcMap. Would anyone be willing to give a step-by-step procedure on this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming you're using ESRI software) Your best bet is to use the [CAD to Geodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000001z000000) tool. Open the search window in ArcMap, type in "CAD to Geodatabase", and when tool pops up follow the prompts. It will create a feature dataset for you in the GDB of your choosing. Inside it you will see all your CAD files. Just know that working with CAD in ESRI software is a constant battle.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, I have been messing with it for days. I finally found a process that works... for this particular drawing. Since the CAD file was funky, I had to redraw a polygon in CAD and project it's coordinate system. Which is a whole 'nother battle! Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: @Natalie Guzman One annoying thing about CAD files is that the coordinates they often come with are a "local" coordinate system, which is something architects use for their drafting. A lot of the time it's by the inch, and not by the foot or meter like most PCSs. Even if they scale it up to the correct unit, they almost never send it with a projection file, so Arcmap projects those coords in same system your dataframe is using. So, to get it to draw correctly you need to have your dataframe in a coordinate system that will draw your CAD file in the correct location. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it actually makes perfect sense. So, as I tried many different ways to project the data frame to coordinates that would match the CAD coordinates, which was a treasure hunt in itself, I actually assigned a coordinate system to the redrawn poly in the CAD drawing, then brought over as an ESRI .shp, then checked the box to not use the default coordinates of LL84, but instead assign to the ones I would need to display the map correctly as there were image files and such I would be displaying underneath it. Thank you for the background on the way the CAD layers are projected!